# Treating spaces and hyphen in a hangman command

Tags: counters, characters, compare

I want to make a hangman command with latex, which use would be \hangman[]{word to guess}, with the following specifications:

1. a switch \ifhide allow to show the hangman or the answer;
2. both hangman or answer appear in a box of the same size;
3. an optionnal argument specifies the horizontal scaling of the box;
4. in hidden mode, the spaces and hyphen should not be hidden.

This first script satisfies 1,2 and 3, but not 4. In addition, an unwanted extra space is added when the command does not start the line.
[image: result of hangman]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof{text}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multido}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newlength{\txtwidth}
\newlength{\txtheight}
\newif\ifhide

\newcommand{\hangman}[2][1.25]{
    \settowidth{\txtwidth}{#2}
    \settoheight{\txtheight}{#2}
    \StrLen{#2}[\n]
    \ifhide
         \resizebox{#1\txtwidth}{!}{ \multido{\i=1+1}{\n}{\_\hspace{0.5ex}} }
    \else
        \makebox[#1\txtwidth]{\Large{#2}}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Test results:} \\

\hidefalse\hangman{test 1}: test with the default size and a space.\\
\hidetrue\hangman{test 1}: test with the default size and a space: needs to show the space.\\

\hidefalse\hangman[2]{test-2}: test with the modified size and a hyphen.\\
\hidetrue\hangman[2]{test-2}: test with the modified size and a hyphen: needs to show the hyphen.\\

Not begining the line: \hidefalse\hangman[2]{test 3}: needs to remove the extra space.\\
Not begining the line: \hidetrue\hangman[2]{test 3}: needs to remove the extra space.\\[5mm]

\end{document}
```

I tried two modifications of the \ifhide instructions to satisfy the 4th criterion. Both generated an error:

first modification:

```
\resizebox{#1\txtlargeur}{!}{ \multido{\k=1+1}{\n}{ \def\chark{\StrChar{#2}{\k}} \IfStrEqCase{\chark}{{ }{ }{-}{-}}[\chark] }  }
```

gave the error (do not trust line number):

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \multido
> {\k =1+1}{\n }{ \def \chark {\StrChar {test 1}{\k }} \IfStrEqCase {\c
> l.28 \hidetrue\hangman{test 1}
> : test of $\backslash$hangman with the default s...
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

second modification:

```
\resizebox{#1\txtlargeur}{!}{%
    \newcounter{k} \setcounter{k}{0}
    \makeatletter
    \@whilenum\value{k}<\n \do{%
        \def\chark{\StrChar{#2}{\value{k}}}
        \IfStrEqCase{\chark}{{ }{ }{-}{-}}[\chark]%
        \stepcounter{k}
    }%
\makeatother
}
```

gave the error:

> l.40 \hidetrue\hangman{test 1}
> : test of $\backslash$hangman with the default s...
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want? Instead of the conditional, I implemented showing with the *-variant. A monospaced font is necessary here, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hangmanrule}{}
 {
  \makebox[0.5em]{\hspace{0.4pt}\hrulefill\hspace{0.4pt}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\hangman}{sO{1.25}m}
 {% #1 = optional * shows the word
  % #2 = optional scale
  % #3 = word
  \scalebox{#2}
   {% scale the result
    \ttfamily
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {% just show the word
      #3
     }
     {% letters must become rules
      \mathteacher_hangman_hide:n { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathteacher_hangman_hide:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [^-\s] } { \c{hangmanrule} } \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hangman*{test}

\hangman{test}

\medskip

\hangman*{test-1}

\hangman{test-1}

\medskip

\hangman*[2]{this is a longer-larger test}

\hangman[2]{this is a longer-larger test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With global setting for “show/hide”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hangmanrule}{}
 {
  \makebox[0.5em]{\hspace{0.4pt}\hrulefill\hspace{0.4pt}}
 }

\bool_new:N \g_mathteacher_hangman_show_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\hangmanshow}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_mathteacher_hangman_show_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hangmanhide}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_mathteacher_hangman_show_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\hangman}{O{1.25}m}
 {% #1 = optional scale
  % #2 = word
  \scalebox{#1}
   {% scale the result
    \ttfamily
    \bool_if:NTF \g_mathteacher_hangman_show_bool
     {% just show the word
      #2
     }
     {% letters must become rules
      \mathteacher_hangman_hide:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathteacher_hangman_hide:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [^-\s] } { \c{hangmanrule} } \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__mathteacher_hangman_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Show}
\hangmanshow

\hangman{test}

\medskip

\hangman{test-1}

\medskip

\hangman[2]{this is a longer-larger test}

\section{Hide}
\hangmanhide

\hangman{test}

\medskip

\hangman{test-1}

\medskip

\hangman[2]{this is a longer-larger test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regex is a good solution. I did not put the hide/show switch as an argument of the function, because i will use a global parameter for all document. Why did you define separately the commands \hangmanrule and \mathteacher_hangman_hide:n ? Readability or a deeper reason? And do the order of those definitions matters?

I notice that the long command names with _ and : forces the use of \ExplSyntaxOn. I don't understand the choice, but i will read the document 'The expl3 package and LaTeX3 programming' and i may come back with some other questions.

Comment: @mathteacher I defined in a “classical” way `\hangmanrule` because it consists of standard (non-expl3) commands. The order doesn't matter. I can change the code to allow for a global setting of show/hide.